# How do I randomize images in Python and how to blit image on top of image?

Tags: python, pygame

*I would like to address 2 questions:*

1.) **How do I randomize images in Python?** I wanted to display a single image everytime I run my program. These are some snippets of my codes, but says some errors. The path was copy and pasted so I'm not so sure why there is an error.

```
import os
import random

path =r"D:\Files\Second Year Files\Advance Compprog\Final Project\Code Blocks\Images\Trivias"
files = os.listdir(path)
d = random.choice(files)
os.startfile(d)
```

**FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Trivia2.png'**

I also tried to use this code but nothings shows up:

```
import pygame
import os
import random

# Initialize the pygame
pygame.init()

screenHeight = 550
screenWidth = 1000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth, screenHeight))

Trivias = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images/Trivias", "Trivia1.png")),
            pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images/Trivias", "Trivia2.png")),
            pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images/Trivias", "Trivia3.png"))]

trivia = random.choice(Trivias)
screen.blit(trivia, [0,0])
```

**2.) How to blit image on top of the other image?**
I tried to blit an image on top of an image but when I run the program, it will just either blink very fast or the last image that I use to blit will display. What if I wanted to blit the first image then, after some time interval, I wanted to overlap it with the other (both images have the same size and will be dsiplayed on the same position). How do I do that and put the time interval as well? I hope you could help me pls :(

```
  background_image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images/Start", "Level1Lose.png"))
  screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])
  pygame.display.update()
  hello_image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Images/Start", "hello.png"))
  screen.blit(hello_image, [0, 0])
  pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer for question 1:

Check `files` variable. It is a list. It may be a list of only file names in that directory, which I think is the case. For proper functioning, it should be a list of paths to the file and not only the file name.

You can resolve this issue by passing `path+d` instead of only `d`

The same argument can be applied to the attempted case.

Comment: Hi i tried doing this but whenever I run the program, my computer just open the file of the image itself. How can I run this in a console in Python? I wanted it to run in a console rather than opening the file. thanx so much pls help :<

Comment: The console window is not capable of displaying images.

Comment: Is there any way I can randomize images and display these images by using screen.blit() in pygame?